# List of Facebook error codes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking for a list of all Facebook can return when you try to fetch infos using Graph API. Can anyone help?

Facebook returns a 400 HTTP error, and a JSON content like:

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "Invalid OAuth access token signature."
   }
}
```

I'm searching the different returns of the same kind it is possible to get.

Comment: I saw this question mentioned https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373459 I just edited to remove the tag.  Tag edits are still possible using the "Edit tags" link beside the tags, even if the question title would have to be lengthened to make other edits.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There seems to be a list now for the errors.

I posted answer for the same question here: [Facebook Graph API error code list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478812/facebook-graph-api-error-code-list/13805173#13805173)

(I found the list here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/error-handling)

Comment: I wish that list were exhaustive. :(

Comment: Do you mean it isn't?

Comment: Nope, it certainly isn't. For example, my API call returns error code -3 with message "Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request". Well, the message basically tells me, what I have to do, but still... And I've encountered more of such codes.

Answer (score 26):

Facebook used to have this published somewhere, but for whatever reason it was removed. But you can find the full list here:
http://www.takwing.idv.hk/tech/fb_dev/faq/general/gen_10.html

Comment: +1 I was looking for this and was annoyed FB took down their original list.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be up to date. For example, if I look for the error message in my question, I can't find it. The messages seem actually to be about the old Rest API...

Answer (score 8):

In case Takwing's copy ever comes down, here's another copy: http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Error_codes

These codes were primarily for the REST API, but they do also come up with the Graph API.  Some of the Graph API calls have underlying FQL calls that return the FQL error codes.  And the direct FQL queries are still part of the currently accepted API.

Update:  I'm trying to keep this list up-to-date.  Please feel free to make changes as you encounter new errors.

Comment: Nice work Tim ☺. Anyway, I still have some problem trying to understand the difference between error code "10" and error code "200"... facebook still doesn't help me in understanding the difference

Comment: I'm not sure, but the 200 code (I think) is specific to the user while 10 seems to be specific to whether an application has access to something.  So, perhaps 10 is seen when you use an application token instead of a user token.

Answer (score 6):

I am trying to keep an updated list of error codes based on previous outdated information.

You can find the repo here http://github.com/phwd/fbec and it has been updated with Test User and Credit Error codes from the Facebook Documentation.

Currently looking for the constant name for "Error Code 2500" and some error descriptions may have changed. I hope to keep on top of this.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official error code page, now:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/error-reference/

It still doesn't look comprehensive...